# Difference between the sphere and RP^2 in the generators and relations of $\pi_1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, projective-space

Here are two drawings we had that I did not quite well understand why they are correct:

> [image]

Here are my questions:

1-I think the drawing of $RP^2$ is meant to be a circle not a disk, am I correct?

2- what should be the generators of $S^2$? And how this leads us to conclude that $\pi_1$ of it is zero?

Could someone clarify these points for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For $RP^2$, its classic definition is indeed the disc quotiented by the relation on the 'edges', so here it indeed is disk, and not a circle
- $S^2$ is simply connected, which precisely means that $\pi_1(S^2)=\{id\}$ is trivial. We can see this either via more general results, or by showing a path on $S^2$ is going to cover some point $x$ finitely many times, then moving the path away from $x$. Then the path has image in $S^2\backslash \{x\}$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is simply connected so the path is homotopic to the constant path.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the last proof? In particular, why a path in $S^2$ is hitting some point $x\in S^2$ only finitely many times?

Comment: are you saying that there are no generators in $S^2$?

Comment: does the surface of genus g is a solid or just the crust?

Comment: is $RP^2$ orientable or not?

Comment: $RP^2$ is not orientable. This can be shown using homology theory. Regarding a reference to my proof of $S^2$ being simply connected, it is from [an example sheet](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/II/Riemann/2023-2024/RS3M23.pdf) in the Cambridge tripos

Comment: The surface of genus g is 'hollow', it is not a 'solid' as it has no 'volume'. And yes $S^2$ has no generator of its fundamental group, as its fundamental group is trivial